# TypeError: snap.data is not a function - Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following helper function in React:

```
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, doc, addDoc, getDoc, setDoc, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage, ref } from 'firebase/storage';
import { FIREBASE_API } from '../config';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(FIREBASE_API);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const storage = getStorage();

export function getDocuments(col) {
    const colRef = collection(db, col);
    const q = query(colRef, where('uid', '==', auth.currentUser.uid));

    getDocs(q).then((snap) => {
        console.log(snap);
        return snap?.data();
    });
    return [];
}
```

Where I am trying to return the documents for a given collection. This is my console output:

[image]

I am trying to figure out why the `data()` method is not available for me to use.. it is a Firestore Database (not Realtime).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDocs()` returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) (contains data of all the documents that matched your query) and not a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot). It has a `docs` property that is an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querydocumentsnapshot) that you can iterate over and read the data of all documents received:

```
export function getDocuments(col) {
    const colRef = collection(db, col);
    const q = query(colRef, where('uid', '==', auth.currentUser.uid));

    return getDocs(q).then((snap) => {
        const data = snap.docs.map((d) => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
}
```